# Unclear appearance of errors during JSON/API processing

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I use riots api (league of legends) to get some information using json/php/curl. I came across a very unclear error message that I do not understand. This code is **not working**:

```
$ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v2.5/league/by-summoner/31827832?api_key=key');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    //var_dump($response);

$json = json_decode($response, true);

     foreach($json['entries'] as $entry){

         echo $entry['playerOrTeamName'] . ',' . $json['tier'] . ',' . $entry['division'] . ',' . $entry['leaguePoints'] . ',' . $entry['wins'] . "<br/>";
        }
```

This is the var_dump in array:

```
{
"name":"Ezreal's Zealots",
"tier":"PLATINUM",
"queue":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
"entries": [{
    "playerOrTeamId":"34458086",
    "playerOrTeamName":"OverdrivZ",
    "division":"V",
    "league‌​Points":21,
    "wins":102,
    "isHotStreak":false,
    "isVeteran":false,
    "isFreshBlood":false‌​,
    "isInactive":false
}]
```

The error message: `Notice: Undefined index: entries in /hermes/bosoraweb130/b411/ipg.notsureifpossiblecom/index.php on line 23` and

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /hermes/bosoraweb130/b411/ipg.notsureifpossiblecom/index.php on line 23`.

Line 23 in my code is:

`foreach($json['entries'][0] as $entry){`

But this exact same code works when i use a different api request:

```
ini_set("display_errors", "1"); error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v2.5/league/challenger?type=RANKED_SOLO_5x5&api_key=key');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

    $json = json_decode($response, true);

        foreach($json['entries'] as $entry){

            echo $entry['playerOrTeamName'] . ',' . $json['tier'] . ',' . $entry['division'] . ',' . $entry['leaguePoints'] . ',' . $entry['wins'] . "<br/>";
            }
```

The only change is in the api url request, the `challenger` version. Why would this code work for this api url request and not for the first one. The echoes I want to execute should work for the entries shown in the array. I dont understand whats going on, must be something very simple? Please help me out.

Comment: Can you add a var_dump with the parsed array(after json_decode())

Comment: gives the same result or am i doing it wrong? These are the api guide references. https://developer.riotgames.com/api/methods#!/828/2919 and https://developer.riotgames.com/api/methods#!/828/2921

the code does not work on 2919 but does work perfectly for 2921. Absolutely no clue how this happened. The var_dump returns just the same results as the first posted array.

Comment: Or did u want to see `var_dump($json)` ? Thats now live on http://20ff.net/

Comment: I wanted var_dump($json) as its the php array.

Comment: yep thats now live on http://20ff.net/

Comment: Ok, it seems there are more levels to the array than shown in the json dump. Can you dump the php array with print_r on 20ff.net so I can run it through beautifier - it will be easier to see the structure.

Comment: okay `print_r($json)` is live on http://20ff.net/ you can also check in the reference guide how its nested. https://developer.riotgames.com/api/methods#!/828/2921

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are two more levels to the array so you actually have:

```
Array (
  [31827832] => Array (
   [0] => Array (
     [name] => Ezreal\'s Zealots
     [tier] => PLATINUM
     [queue] => RANKED_SOLO_5x5
     [entries] => Array (
       [0] => Array (
       [playerOrTeamId] => 34458086
       [playerOrTeamName] => OverdrivZ
       [division] => V
       [leaguePoints] => 21
       [wins] => 102
       [isHotStreak] =>
       [isVeteran] =>
       [isFreshBlood] =>
       [isInactive] =>
    )
```

Ok, so it seems the first entry in the array is actually integer index with the id of the player so I guess there is an API call to get it, but in this case use this:

```
$json = array_pop($json);
foreach($json[0]['entries'] as $entry){
    ....
}
```

Comment: Tried the code, but did not work. Its just strange because the exact same code does work for the exact same api reference guide, the only thing that is changing is the output. Both api references use the exact same request handling. This is very strange behaviour. Error message after using your code: `Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /hermes/bosoraweb130/b411/ipg.notsureifpossiblecom/index.php on line 23 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /hermes/bosoraweb130/b411/ipg.notsureifpossiblecom/index.php on line 23`

Comment: The structure of the parsed JSON differs from the give JSON try looping through the items of the parsed array and print_r the result to test the structure. I'll edit the code.

Comment: your edited code works good. Could you please explain why this behavior occured? I still dont understand what went wrong.

Comment: The JSON object comes encapsulated in two additional levels - first is the ID holding the main Array. Its used as the array index and because its an integer when parsed you cant access it with $arr[0], but you must you the exact index. In the given example you don't know its value so you pop the array to get the next level which is zero indexed array holding the real response data you need. That last object is actually the part you pasted. Probably somewhere in their API they explain the encapsulation they use for the responses.